# Subquery returning more then one value but it shouldn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, set

I'm trying to update a lt_esp table -- to say set the season_desc column to the description value from the tr_season column.

The season value in lt_esp table is equivalent to the id from tr_season. Each line in table has a season value, however the season value isn't unique it can repeat many lines can have the season = 224. What i want to happen is if season = 224 then we find the id 224 in tr_season an whatever the description there we update our lt_esp tables.

```
update a
set a.season_desc = b.[description]
from [tr_esp] a
join tr_season b on a.season = b.id
where customer_no = 3773541 
-- a.season_desc is null
```

tr_season has id, description and a few other questions 
tr_esp has season (equivalent to id) and season_desc (equivalent to description)

I keep getting this error message but it doesn't make sense because each line has only one season value.

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ltg_esp_trigger, Line 11
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: sql server 2008, sorry the mysql was suggested and i clicked too soon. it can be removed

Comment: what is in your procedure "ltg_esp_trigger" on line 11 ?

Comment: line 11 just says -- ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ltg_esp_trigger]

Comment: Probably your trigger is written as though the update would only affect one row and is broken. `inserted` and `deleted` can contain `0`, `1` or many rows depending on how many rows the statement affected.

Comment: jus sayin, you say in your description of the issue that the update target table is one mr. lt_esp but in the update statement you mention one mr. tr_esp.

Comment: @WhirlMind sorry those are one and the same --  a typo on my part. they should read lt_esp across the board.

Comment: Your trigger is the problem. Post the code for your trigger. It almost certainly has a subquery that is returning more than 1 row. This is a VERY common mistake in triggers.

Comment: The trigger is very long - is it an issue if i turn off the trigger run this update (as i'm simply updating one column here) and then turn the trigger back on? Are there issues with doing that?

Comment: @YelizavetaYR  this issue  may be affecting other part of your code

Comment: At the least, can you look for some portion of the code in the trigger that has a subquery (that assumes one record but inadvertently fetches many) ? If you post the portions having subqueries, one may be able to give more pointers. ?

Comment: Yes there are concurrency issues with trying to turn off a trigger, do something, and then restore it.  OTHER connections might try inserting or updating data while your process has the trigger disabled.  Triggers are global resources, not per-connection. It's a VERY bad practice to try and get around things by doing that.

Comment: @pmbAustin yes I understand, and its on my radar to review the trigger. I have reviewed my code and found it successful in a dev environment while the trigger is disabled but before pushing it to the live environment I will go through the trigger.